# Prove that a connected graph with $n$ vertices of degree $4$ and $2n+2$ vertices of degree $1$ doesn't have cycle

Tags: graph-theory

To me it seems that it boils down to proving that $G$ is a tree.
I know that a tree has the property that the sum of the degrees of all vertices is equal to $2|V|-2$.

And we have $n$ vertices of degree $4$ and $2n+2$ vertices of degree $1$ so the sum is equal to:

$\sum _{v\in V}\delta \left(v\right)=2\left|E\right|=6n+2\:$

and it has to be equal to $2|V|-2$ which is $6n+4-2=6n+2$ thus $G$ is a tree and doesn't have cycles. Is this correct?

Comment: I think that, besides assuming that your graph is connected and has $n$ vertices of degree $4$ and $2n+2$ vertices of degree $1,$ you also want to assume that there are **no other vertices.**